# Flash player does not work probably with Arabic language

Tags: flash, arabic, rtl

The Flash plug-in version 11.2 which is the latest version does not support the Arabic language.

It shows the characters separated and oriented from left to right; whereas it has to display them as joined characters and oriented right to left.

Adobe says that they will only provide a security update and nothing else, so that clear bug will be kept for Firefox, Opera and other browsers that depend on the standalone plug-in.

Google Chrome display the language correctly because of it's own built in plug-in.

[image]

Comment: Since Adobe won't fix it, I am afraid we'll have to live with it. Hopefully, the reliance on flash will decrease over the next couple of years.

Comment: Sorry I didn't see your answer but now. You are right HTML5 is the total next solution. But also it's not working in all videos it's a clear case this problem has to be fixed for the previous videos on the web it's my personal opinion as an end user. You as a developer or maybe others could find the solution for such case that's why I unaccepted the answer maybe we can forward it as a bug or something. Tell me what to do ?

Answer (score 4):

Since Adobe will not update flash for Linux.

> Adobe will no longer provide new releases of Flash Player for Linux
>   after version 11.2, the company has today announced.
>
> Google will, instead, take over the implementation of Flash Player via
>   a new plugin API called ‘Pepper‘.<sup>1</sup>

Consider using HTML 5 instead of flash for You Tube.  It doesn't have that problem.  As you see in the below image, it doesn't have the problem.

<sup>1</sup>Source:[OMG](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/02/adobe-adandons-flash-on-linux)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your useful answer. HTML5 is a great solution. Hope it'll totally replace the flash player on all the websites.

Comment: @user134326 Why did you unaccept the answer?  What's wrong?

Comment: Also I forgot something all Facebook videos running only in Adobe flash player :( unfortunately.

Comment: I think that you should have included that in your question, since I answered according to what you had listed.  You can try an older version on Flash.  Try [fp_10.3.183.90_archive.zip](http://download.macromedia.com/pub/flashplayer/installers/archive/fp_10.3.183.90_archive.zip), and for instructions on how to install see this [file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/laqfi7z7xhvw1q9/flash.txt).

Comment: Just to mention, This a bug is related to Dynamic TextBox of Flash even Windows was suffering from it. No hope

Answer (score -1):

You can go to https://www.youtube.com/html5 and activate the HTML5 player, it works for me.