# How can I get non-English characters to render on Flash?

Tags: flash, fonts

On Flash, I've noticed that Kana and other language's scripts are not rendering properly and replacing themselves with boxes.

I have the correct fonts installed and the scripts render well and are fine on all other things except for Flash websites.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Take a look at this [Post](http://askubuntu.com/questions/270934/flash-player-does-not-work-probably-with-arabic-language/270977#270977), it might give you a start.

Comment: Hey, what's wrong with boxes? Boxes are cool!

Comment: Not funny, Seth! Trust me, when you're trying to remember Kanji...

Comment: @Mitch Unfortunately I cannot change it to HTML 5 because it's not my website :( It works on Windows and OS X though.

Comment: I think @Mitch meant this: http://www.youtube.com/html5

Comment: @Seth It's not YouTube o__o

Comment: Is more likely that you need the fonts. Is a pain in the arse to do it. But it can be done... just install as many "standard" fonts you can find ;).